# C program crasher or gives unexpected output

Tags: c

I was given this code to look at and find the problem of why its crashing or giving unexpected output. I can not seem to find it so a little hint or help would be great.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

char* strdup(const char *s)
{
    size_t len = strlen(s);
    char d[len+1];
    return strncpy(d, s, len+1);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i;
    for(i = 1; i < argc; i++){
        puts(strdup(argv[i]));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hint: Your local `strdup()` function returns a `char *`.  To what does that pointer point?

Comment: @EugeneSh. The one I found is actual C++ ... but it's the same problem and the top answer there is equally relevant to C, IMHO.

Comment: @JohnBollinger it tries to return copied character which is const char *s

Comment: No, @ShahinMamedov, it does not.  Pointers point to *objects*, not to *values*.  To what object does the pointer point?

Comment: @JohnBollinger to char *argv?

Comment: Now you're just guessing.  Your function returns the return value of its `strncpy()` call, but what's that?  It's understandable if you don't know off the top of your head what `strncpy()` returns, but you need to know how to *look that up*.  Try Googling "man strncpy".

Comment: @JohnBollinger I know what strncpy is, I know that strdup returns d, copied from s with length.

Comment: And `d` is a *local* array.  Here ends the hint.